# Unselect the Gtk TreeSelection when cleraing the TreeStore model

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I followed the python-gtk-3-tutorial and implemented a simple file browser using Gtk TreeView. It works pretty well, but but my problem is, that by the time of the initialization the first item in the TreeView is already selected by default.

I initialize the TreeSelection using :

```
treeSelection = treeView.get_selection()
```

Then I connect the tree selection with a callback function:

```
treeSelection.connect("changed", treeSelectionChanged)

def treeSelectionChanged(treeSelection):
        treeModel, treeIter = treeSelection.get_selected()
        if treeIter != None:
            print "You selected", treeModel[treeIter][0]
```

When my app starts the first entry in the TreeView is already selected and it's name is printed out. If I re-read the data and clear the tree-model (*treeStore.clear()*) I also get responses to "changes" in the TreeView and the names of other items in the TreeView are also printed out.

I do not know how to unselect the selection made by default and unselect all items before clearing the TreeStore. I could not figure out how. Could please someone point me to my mistake ? Here is the example code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, stat
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Simple Photo Importer", default_width = 400,default_height = 600)
        # initialize new Gtk box container
        self.fileSystemTreeBox = Gtk.Box.new(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 5)
        self.add(self.fileSystemTreeBox)


        # initialize the filesystem treestore
        self.fileSystemTreeStore = Gtk.TreeStore(str, Pixbuf, str, bool)
        # populate the tree store
        self.populateFileSystemTreeStore(self.fileSystemTreeStore, '/home/karlitos')
        # initialize the TreeView
        self.fileSystemTreeView = Gtk.TreeView(self.fileSystemTreeStore)#, default_width = 400,default_height = 600)
        self.fileSystemTreeView.set_headers_visible(False)
        #self.fileSystemTreeView.columns_autosize()
        # Create a TreeViewColumn
        treeViewCol = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(title=None)
        treeViewCol.set_sizing(Gtk.TreeViewColumnSizing.AUTOSIZE)
        #treeViewCol.expand = True

        # Create a column cell to display text
        colCellText = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        # Create a column cell to display an image
        colCellImg = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
        # Add the cells to the column
        treeViewCol.pack_start(colCellImg, False)
        treeViewCol.pack_start(colCellText, True)
        # Bind the text cell to column 0 of the tree's model
        treeViewCol.add_attribute(colCellText, "text", 0)
        # Bind the image cell to column 1 of the tree's model
        treeViewCol.add_attribute(colCellImg, "pixbuf", 1)
        # Append the columns to the TreeView
        self.fileSystemTreeView.append_column(treeViewCol)
        # add "on expand" callback
        self.fileSystemTreeView.connect("row-expanded", self.onRowExpanded)
        # add "on collapse" callback
        self.fileSystemTreeView.connect("row-collapsed", self.onRowCollapsed)

        # add tree view selection
        fileSystemTreeSelection = self.fileSystemTreeView.get_selection()
        fileSystemTreeSelection.connect("changed", self.fileSystemTreeSelectionChanged)

        # add scroll view 
        self.scrollView = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrollView.add(self.fileSystemTreeView)
        # append the scrollView to the window (this)
        #self.add(self.scrollView)
        self.fileSystemTreeBox.pack_start(self.scrollView, True, True, 0)

        # add a button for selecting different folder
        self.readNewDirButton = Gtk.Button(label="Read new directory")
        self.readNewDirButton.connect("clicked", self.readNewDirectory)
        #self.add(self.readNewDirButton)
        self.fileSystemTreeBox.pack_start(self.readNewDirButton, False, False, 0)

    def populateFileSystemTreeStore(self, treeStore, path, parent=None):
        appendHiddenItems = False
        folders = []
        files = []
        # iterate over the items in the path
        for item in os.listdir(path):
            # skip item if it's name brgiins with '.' and appendHiddenItems ist set to 'false'
            if not appendHiddenItems and item[0] == '.': continue
            # Get the absolute path of the item
            itemFullname = os.path.join(path, item)
            # Extract metadata from the item
            itemMetaData = os.stat(itemFullname)
            # Determine if the item is a folder
            itemIsFolder = stat.S_ISDIR(itemMetaData.st_mode)
            # Generate an icon from the default icon theme
            itemIcon = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon("folder" if itemIsFolder else "empty", 22, 0)
            # Append the item with corresponding metadata to related arrays
            if itemIsFolder:
                folders.append([item, itemIcon, itemFullname, itemIsFolder])
            else:
                files.append([item, itemIcon, itemFullname, itemIsFolder])
        # append dummy when no entries in the current folder
        if not folders and not files: treeStore.append(parent, [None, None, None, None])
        else:
            for folderEntry in sorted(folders):
                # append the folders
                currentIter = treeStore.append(parent, folderEntry)
                # append the dummy nodes to the folders
                treeStore.append(currentIter, [None, None, None, None])
            for fileEntry in sorted(files):
                treeStore.append(parent, fileEntry)

    def onRowExpanded(self, treeView, treeIter, treePath):
        # get the associated model
        treeStore = treeView.get_model()
        # get the full path of the position
        newPath = treeStore.get_value(treeIter, 2)
        # populate the subtree on curent position
        self.populateFileSystemTreeStore(treeStore, newPath, treeIter)
        # remove the first child (dummy node)
        treeStore.remove(treeStore.iter_children(treeIter))

    def onRowCollapsed(self, treeView, treeIter, treePath):
        # get the associated model
        treeStore = treeView.get_model()
        # get the iterator of the first child
        currentChildIter = treeStore.iter_children(treeIter)
        # loop as long as some childern exist
        while currentChildIter:
            # remove the first child
            treeStore.remove(currentChildIter)
            # refresh the iterator of the next child
            currentChildIter = treeStore.iter_children(treeIter)
        # append dummy node
        treeStore.append(treeIter, [None, None, None, None])

    def readNewDirectory(self, widget):
        # initialize the open directory dialog
        openDirectoryDialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a folder", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER, (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,
            Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL, "Select", Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        openDirectoryDialog.set_default_size(800, 400)
        # initialize the response
        openDirectoryResponse = openDirectoryDialog.run()
        if openDirectoryResponse == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            self.fileSystemTreeStore.clear()
            self.populateFileSystemTreeStore(self.fileSystemTreeStore, openDirectoryDialog.get_filename())
        #elif openDirectoryResponse == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            #do something
        openDirectoryDialog.destroy()

    def fileSystemTreeSelectionChanged(self, fileSystemTreeSelection):
        fileSystemTreeModel, fileSystemTreeIter = fileSystemTreeSelection.get_selected()#_rows()
        if fileSystemTreeIter != None:
            print "You selected", fileSystemTreeModel[fileSystemTreeIter][0]

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that does exactly what you ask, but would not work in the `__init__` of your example, this function is called `unselect_all`, and belongs to Gtk.TreeSelection.
So I took the riverbed to edit his example.

Forgive English, is extracted from the Google translator.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, stat
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Simple Photo Importer", default_width = 400,default_height = 600)
        # initialize new Gtk box container
        self.firstSelection = True
        self.fileSystemTreeBox = Gtk.Box.new(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 5)
        self.add(self.fileSystemTreeBox)


        # initialize the filesystem treestore
        self.fileSystemTreeStore = Gtk.TreeStore(str, Pixbuf, str, bool)
        # populate the tree store
        self.populateFileSystemTreeStore(self.fileSystemTreeStore, os.path.expanduser('~'))
        # initialize the TreeView
        self.fileSystemTreeView = Gtk.TreeView(self.fileSystemTreeStore)#, default_width = 400,default_height = 600)
        self.fileSystemTreeView.set_headers_visible(False)
        #self.fileSystemTreeView.columns_autosize()
        # Create a TreeViewColumn
        treeViewCol = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(title=None)
        treeViewCol.set_sizing(Gtk.TreeViewColumnSizing.AUTOSIZE)
        #treeViewCol.expand = True

        # Create a column cell to display text
        colCellText = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        # Create a column cell to display an image
        colCellImg = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
        # Add the cells to the column
        treeViewCol.pack_start(colCellImg, False)
        treeViewCol.pack_start(colCellText, True)
        # Bind the text cell to column 0 of the tree's model
        treeViewCol.add_attribute(colCellText, "text", 0)
        # Bind the image cell to column 1 of the tree's model
        treeViewCol.add_attribute(colCellImg, "pixbuf", 1)
        # Append the columns to the TreeView
        self.fileSystemTreeView.append_column(treeViewCol)
        # add "on expand" callback
        self.fileSystemTreeView.connect("row-expanded", self.onRowExpanded)
        # add "on collapse" callback
        self.fileSystemTreeView.connect("row-collapsed", self.onRowCollapsed)

        # add tree view selection
        fileSystemTreeSelection = self.fileSystemTreeView.get_selection()
        fileSystemTreeSelection.connect("changed", self.fileSystemTreeSelectionChanged)

        # add scroll view
        self.scrollView = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrollView.add(self.fileSystemTreeView)
        # append the scrollView to the window (this)
        #self.add(self.scrollView)
        self.fileSystemTreeBox.pack_start(self.scrollView, True, True, 0)

        # add a button for selecting different folder
        self.readNewDirButton = Gtk.Button(label="Read new directory")
        self.readNewDirButton.connect("clicked", self.readNewDirectory)
        #self.add(self.readNewDirButton)
        self.fileSystemTreeBox.pack_start(self.readNewDirButton, False, False, 0)

    def populateFileSystemTreeStore(self, treeStore, path, parent=None):
        appendHiddenItems = False
        folders = []
        files = []
        # iterate over the items in the path
        for item in os.listdir(path):
            # skip item if it's name brgiins with '.' and appendHiddenItems ist set to 'false'
            if not appendHiddenItems and item[0] == '.': continue
            # Get the absolute path of the item
            itemFullname = os.path.join(path, item)
            # Extract metadata from the item
            itemMetaData = os.stat(itemFullname)
            # Determine if the item is a folder
            itemIsFolder = stat.S_ISDIR(itemMetaData.st_mode)
            # Generate an icon from the default icon theme
            itemIcon = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon("folder" if itemIsFolder else "empty", 22, 0)
            # Append the item with corresponding metadata to related arrays
            if itemIsFolder:
                folders.append([item, itemIcon, itemFullname, itemIsFolder])
            else:
                files.append([item, itemIcon, itemFullname, itemIsFolder])
        # append dummy when no entries in the current folder
        if not folders and not files: treeStore.append(parent, [None, None, None, None])
        else:
            for folderEntry in sorted(folders):
                # append the folders
                currentIter = treeStore.append(parent, folderEntry)
                # append the dummy nodes to the folders
                treeStore.append(currentIter, [None, None, None, None])
            for fileEntry in sorted(files):
                treeStore.append(parent, fileEntry)

    def onRowExpanded(self, treeView, treeIter, treePath):
        # get the associated model
        treeStore = treeView.get_model()
        # get the full path of the position
        newPath = treeStore.get_value(treeIter, 2)
        # populate the subtree on curent position
        self.populateFileSystemTreeStore(treeStore, newPath, treeIter)
        # remove the first child (dummy node)
        treeStore.remove(treeStore.iter_children(treeIter))

    def onRowCollapsed(self, treeView, treeIter, treePath):
        # get the associated model
        treeStore = treeView.get_model()
        # get the iterator of the first child
        currentChildIter = treeStore.iter_children(treeIter)
        # loop as long as some childern exist
        while currentChildIter:
            # remove the first child
            treeStore.remove(currentChildIter)
            # refresh the iterator of the next child
            currentChildIter = treeStore.iter_children(treeIter)
        # append dummy node
        treeStore.append(treeIter, [None, None, None, None])

    def readNewDirectory(self, widget):
        # initialize the open directory dialog
        openDirectoryDialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a folder", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER, (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,
            Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL, "Select", Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        openDirectoryDialog.set_default_size(800, 400)
        # initialize the response
        openDirectoryResponse = openDirectoryDialog.run()
        if openDirectoryResponse == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            self.fileSystemTreeStore.clear()
            self.populateFileSystemTreeStore(self.fileSystemTreeStore, openDirectoryDialog.get_filename())
        #elif openDirectoryResponse == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            #do something
        openDirectoryDialog.destroy()

    def fileSystemTreeSelectionChanged(self, fileSystemTreeSelection):
        fileSystemTreeModel, fileSystemTreeIter = fileSystemTreeSelection.get_selected()#_rows()
        if fileSystemTreeIter != None and not self.firstSelection:
            print "You selected", fileSystemTreeModel[fileSystemTreeIter][0]

        elif self.firstSelection:
            fileSystemTreeSelection.unselect_all()
            self.firstSelection = False

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Why does it print out the content of the first opened folder upon the first folder change ? I have the same problem with in my code. If you change the directory it prints the content of the home directory twice.